# How to build native Eclipse launcher?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, launcher

I want to modify Eclipse launcher so it will behave like a watchdog (restarting process, if it dies unexpectedly). Where can I find more information about how to patch Eclipse launcher, and build it for different platforms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find Eclipse launcher sources at http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.equinox/framework/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.executable/library/?root=RT_Project
Building scripts for different platforms are there too.
eclipse.c is the entry point so it makes sense to put your platform-independent code there.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Are there build instructions / prerequisites somewhere?